# Jquery-Jtable remove child table icon when child table is empty

Tags: jquery, jtable

I am using Jquery's Jtable plugin. Is there a simple way to hide the icons of the child table if the child table is empty? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If child table is empty, then disable the icon or image on which (clicking on it) you are showing the Child table. I think this will solve the problem.

Comment: The way `jQuery jTable` was implemented, you can NOT know before hand if it's empty or not.